# I want to uninstall Wine from Ubuntu. How can I do that?

Tags: wine

Is it safe to use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

when removing wine? Will it make any changes to other installed applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you cite, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, will not remove Wine -- it will only remove packages that are "no longer needed" -- for instance, dependencies for packages that are no longer installed.  To remove Wine, you'll need the correct command to remove the Wine packages.

Comment: Can you mention the correct command because I have tried several ways and could not make it unintall

Comment: I'm not at my Ubuntu system at present, but it should be something like `apt-get purge package' with the correct Wine package name inserted.  Care is recommended, however, because there may be other things you use that depend on Wine.